# Convert CSV rows into columns in Java

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I have a CSV like the following

```
Element,Value
LIN,887873083091
QTY,12
LIN,887873083107
QTY,13
LIN,887873083114
QTY,10
LIN,887873083121
QTY,6
LIN,887873083138
QTY,0
Avialability,018
Avail_Date,20391231
LIN,887873083145
QTY,0
Avialability,018
Avail_Date,20391231
LIN,886732553461
QTY,0
Avialability,018
Avail_Date,20391231
LIN,886732637901
QTY,0
Avialability,018
Avail_Date,20391231
LIN,886732637918
QTY,0
Avialability,018
Avail_Date,20391231
LIN,886732637925
QTY,0
Avialability,018
Avail_Date,20391231
LIN,886732637932
QTY,0
Avialability,018
Avail_Date,20391231
LIN,886732637949
QTY,0
Avialability,018
Avail_Date,20391231
LIN,886732637956
QTY,0
Avialability,018
Avail_Date,20391231
LIN,886732637963
QTY,0
Avialability,018
Avail_Date,20391231
LIN,886732637970
QTY,0
Avialability,018
Avail_Date,20391231
```

As you can see there are 4 elements. **LIN,QTY,Availability,Avail_Date**

I want to make these elements as columns and put values under it and make it as a CSV file.

Like the following sample

```
LIN,QTY,Availability,Avail_Date
887873083091,12,,
887873083107,13,,
887873083114,10,,
887873083121,6,,
887873083138,0,018,20391231
887873083145,0,018,20391231
886732553461,0,018,20391231
```

The original one follows the order LIN, QTY, Availability and Avail_Date .. But the Availability and Avail_Date may be missing in some cases. That cases I want to put blank to new CSV like the first 4 rows in sample output.

How can I write a Java code for that? can anyone give any solution? I havn't tried anything since I don't get any idea

Comment: Where is the code you have tried so far?

Comment: I havn't tried anything aince I don't get any idea

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough outline to get you started:

1. Create a simple helper class which has this properties: LIN,QTY,Availability,Avail_Date.
2. Read line by line
3. Create a new instance of your helper class and put it into an ArrayList.
4. For every line call split()
5. Fill in the appropriate property of your helper class.
6. If you detect that you read a new object, create a new instance of the helper class.
7. After reading the file loop over your ArrayList and write a line to your output file.

Just try and if you get stuck, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] colName = {"LIN","QTY","Availability","Avail_Date"};
    String output = "";

    int colNum = 0;

    // Using file handling read row one by one (readUTF method) : this is sudo code only
    // or you can use the CSV parser
    while(!EOF)
    {

      // spilt key and value using ","

       for(int i = colNum;i<colName.length;i++){

         if(colName[i].equals(key)){
            output = output  + value + ","
            break;
         }else{
             output = output  ","
         }

       }
       colNum = i;

       if(colNum == colName.length ){
          output = output  "\n";
          colNum = 0;
       }
} // end while
```

I have not run this code. so may be some small changes require.